# ThreeJS loader loadAsync promise resolves to null without any error

Tags: javascript, async-await, three.js

I wanted to download texture files parallel to improve loading times, but it seems like out of my 9 texture files, only my normals are being set to null.

Everything works fine, if I just use load instead. I do not need the promise to resolve immediately as I am using threejs' loading manager as well.

```js
textureLoader.loadAsync(assets.normal).then(res => this.textures['normal'] = res).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Here is my actual code.

Synchronous code

```js
this.textures = {
    moon: {
        texture: textureLoader.load(assets.moon.texture),
        normal: textureLoader.load(assets.moon.normal),
    },
    starfield: assets.starfield.map(tex => {
        return textureLoader.load(tex);
    }),
    starSprite: textureLoader.load(assets.starSprite),
}
```

Async code

```js
this.textures = {
    moon: {
        texture: null,
        normal: null
    },
    starfield: {
        right: null,
        left: null,
        top: null,
        bottom: null,
        front: null,
        back: null
    },
    starSprite: null
};
textureLoader.loadAsync(assets.moon.texture).then(res => this.textures.moon.texture = res);
textureLoader.loadAsync(assets.moon.normal).then(res => this.textures.moon.normal = res);
['right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom', 'front', 'back'].forEach(tex => 
    textureLoader.loadAsync(assets.starfield[tex]).then(res => this.textures.starfield[tex] = res)
);
textureLoader.loadAsync(assets.starSprite).then(res => this.textures.starSprite = res);
```

Do note that I only consume textures after the LoadingManger calls its onLoad()

You can find the entire project here https://github.com/Blakeinstein/Blakeinstein.github.io/blob/master/src/js/sketch.ts

Comment: Please demonstrate the issue with a live example. `loadAsync()` works as expected in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q0om1hac/

Comment: Its difficult to demonstrate since I myself am only facing this issue on a single file out of the 9 assets in total that I am loading via the same.

Comment: I have since updated my original question. I cannot provide an MRE because, it looks like its slightly specific to my case.